# Setting UILocalNotification's applicationIconBadgeNumber

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

When I set up the localnotification's applicationIconBadgeNumber, do I put just 1, knowing that it will be adding to the total, or do I put the total?

e.g.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotif2.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

OR

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotif2.applicationIconBadgeNumber = Total;
```

(However, I won't be able predict the total number of notification that the user has read at any given time in time...which will mean, if the second method is true than I'm screwed.)

Answer (score 3):

Second is true. Always set the total value. You have to recalculate all your noitifications every time your app is opened.

Also the documentation states `The application should use this property’s value to increment the current icon badge number, if any.`, it is NOT incrementing on its own.

Comment: your comment sounds good to me, even tho the original answer contradicts it. thx for looking that up.

Comment: I mean you have to set your self according to your logic. If you set badge number with array count, Then its 12, Let suppose one notification hit then set badge number to array-1. Confirmed me please

Comment: i've tested it now. You have to calculate this before! It is NOT incrementing on its own. (So same behaviour as with push notifications, as expected)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible, You can handle it from your code.

Comment: I mean you have to set your self according to your logic. If you set badge number with array count, Then its 12, Let suppose one notification hit then set badge number to array-1.